# disable floating point literals in QTextEdit

Tags: qt, floating-point, format, qtextedit

I calculate and print some big numbers on a QTextEdit; one number per row (paragraph). The numbers convert themselves to floating point literals like 3.45345e-08. The widget QTextEdit is wide enough, if it matters.

I need a setting that disables the floating-point-literals format of QTextEdit.

Comment: QTextEdit accepts text and doesn't perform any number formatting. The issue could be in how you convert numbers to text. Please show us some code.

Comment: I sppupose this short example coul’d be suficient

#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextEdit t;
    double x = 1234567890.1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        x *= 1.6182;    // some kind of calculations
        t.append(QString::number(x));
    }

    t.show();

    return a.exec();
}

Comment: I have it already: t.append(QString::number(x,'f', 2));